# apt can't find php8.2 even though I have added the ondrej/php ppa in my Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: apt, php, ppa

I have added the ondrej/php ppa but it can only find the php8.1 version of php not the other ones.

Comment: Did you look at https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php which shows what releases support is provided for, ie. only *standard* support LTS releases.  Ubuntu 23.04 isn't a LTS release.

Comment: @guiverc Seems like it only supports Jammy and focal series. So I guess i can't install php from ondrej ppa?

Comment: I mentioned it only supports LTS releases in *standard* support; which is *focal* (20.04) & *jammy* (22.04) currently. The PPA you mention does **not** provide support for *non-LTS* like *lunar* or 23.04 as already stated.